# Probably Primitive Polynomials Redux

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields, factoring, irreducible-polynomials

Modulus $2$, is $1+x^{10}+x^{11}+x^{18}+x^{1277}$ a primitive polynomial?
Modulus $3$, is $1 + 2 x^{87} + x^{661}$ a primitive polynomial?
Modulus $5$, is $3 + 2 x^{28} + x^{431}$ a primitive polynomial?
Modulus $7$, is $4 + 2 x^{4} + 6 x^{5} + x^{359}$ a primitive polynomial?

Amusingly, soon after my run finished for finding $3 + 2 x^{28} + x^{431}$, [NFS@Home snfs finished](http://homes.cerias.purdue.edu/~ssw/cun/page134) the [factorization of $5^{431}-1$](http://www.mersennewiki.org/index.php/5_Minus_Tables). I can verify that polynomial is primitive.

I found these by searching for low weight irreducible polynomial that "passed" for low factors.   As shown at [Probably Primitive Polynomials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2381574/probably-primitive-polynomials), irreducible but not primitive polynomials always exist if the corresponding (prime power - 1) is factorable. But these irreducible polynomials tend to have high weight.

$x^{((3^{661} - 1)/d)} \mod{(1 + 2 x^{87} + x^{661}, 3)} \equiv 2$ for $d=2$, the only known divisor for $3^{661} - 1$. Since the modulus doesn't equal 1, we can say that irreducible polynomial passes for that divisor. If a modulus $\equiv 1$ for a given divisor, it fails. What are low weight irreducible but not primitive polynomials requiring larger divisors to fail?

Mod $2$, $1 + x^{21} + x^{54}$ fails for divisors $87211$ and $262657$.
Mod $2$, $1 + x^{14} + x^{147}$ fails for divisors $4432676798593$ and $2741672362528725535068727$.
Mod $3$, $1 + x^4 + 2 x^5 + x^{75}$ fails for divisor $8951$.
Mod $5$, $3 + x^2 + x^3 + x^{85}$ fails for divisor $1531$.
Mod $7$, $3 + 2 x^2 + x^{32}$ fails for divisor $1201\times2$.

What are other low-weight polynomials that only fail for large divisors? Are the polynomial $1 + x^{21} + x^{54}$ and $1 + x^{14} + x^{147}$ special in some way? Are there other small weight polynomials that only fail for a 10+ digit divisors?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that in general such questions are difficult. I did spot the following obvious obstructions to primitivity.

- The polynomial $p(x)=1+x^{21}+x^{54}$ can be rewritten as $q(x^3)$ with $q(x)=1+x^7+x^{18}$. Clearly $q(x)$ is irreducible also, for if it were not, then $p(x)$ would not be irreducible either. This means that any zero of $q(x)$ has order that is a factor of $2^{18}-1$. Consequently the order of a zero of $p(x)$ is a factor of $3\cdot(2^{18}-1)=786429$.
- Similarly the polynomial $r(x)=1+x^{14}+x^{147}=s(x^7)$ where $s(x)=1+x^2+x^{21}$. Again, as $s(x)$ is irreducible, the zeros of $r(x)$ have order at most $7\cdot(2^{21}-1)=14680057$.

It always happens that if $f(x)\in\Bbb{F}_p[x]$ is primitive of degree $n$, and $\ell$ is a prime number such that $\ell\mid p^n-1$, then $g(x)=f(x^\ell)$ is irreducible, but obviously not primitive. After all, any root of $g(x)$ must be of order $\ell(p^n-1)$ (need $\ell\mid p^n-1$ for this to hold). If $\ell^t$ is the highest power of $\ell$ that divides $p^n-1$, then 
$$
p^n=1+k\cdot\ell^t
$$
with $\gcd(k,\ell)=1$, and it easily follows that $p$ has order $n\ell$ modulo $\ell^{t+1}$. This means that the roots of $g(x)$ generate an extension field of degree $\ell n$. In other words, $g(x)$ is irreducible.

Comment: This also explains the mod 7 $3+2x^2+x^{32}$ case.

Comment: Indeed, @EdPegg